# How to update SQL query for a virtual layer?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, sql, virtual-layer, update-query

I created a virtual layer which contains all the geometries and attributes from a shapefile using the following code:

```
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer( "?layer=ogr:path/to/shapefile", "layerName", "virtual" )
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

But now I want to update the SQL query for this virtual layer. Is this possible using PyQGIS?

---

Example:

How could I update the virtual layer with the following simple query:

```
SELECT * FROM anotherLayer WHERE ID < 10
```

Comment: Are you wanting a subset of the virtual layer?

Comment: @artwork21 - No, not a subset. My idea (for a plugin) was to have a single virtual layer which 'duplicates' another layer in terms of geometry and attributes. So if I have two layers (`"layer1"` and `"layer2"`) and one virtual layer, if the user selects `"layer1"` from the plugin, the virtual layer will be updated to be exactly like `"layer1"`. And vice-versa if the user selects `"layer2"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be enough to update the layer data source with an appropriate URI. See the following examples involving 2 layers from Natural Earth ([airports](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/cultural/ne_10m_airports.zip) and [countries](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/cultural/ne_10m_admin_0_countries.zip)) and 2 different queries for each layer.

```
pathAirports = u'/docs/geodata/world/ne_10m_airports.shp'
pathCountries = u'/docs/geodata/world/ne_10m_admin_0_countries.shp' 

queryAirports="SELECT * FROM airports"
queryAirports2="SELECT * FROM airports WHERE type='major'"
queryCountries="SELECT * FROM countries"
queryCountries2="SELECT * FROM countries WHERE SUBREGION='South America'"

layer = QgsVectorLayer(
            "?layer=ogr:{}:airports&query={}".format( pathAirports, queryAirports ),
            "Airports",
            "virtual" )
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer( layer )

layer.setDataSource(
            "?layer=ogr:{}:airports&query={}".format( pathAirports, queryAirports2 ),
            "Some Airports", 
            "virtual" )

layer.setDataSource(
            "?layer=ogr:{}:countries&query={}".format( pathCountries, queryCountries ),
            "Countries", 
            "virtual" )

layer.setDataSource(
            "?layer=ogr:{}:countries&query={}".format( pathCountries, queryCountries2 ), 
            "Some countries", 
            "virtual" )
```

---

*However, there seems to be a bug with Virtual Layers that doesn't allow you to select features properly using canvas tools. For instance, after running the last line above, I cannot select `Brasil` using the select tool (it keeps selecting `Argentina`!). I've confirmed this on QGIS v2.14.8 (GNU/Linux), QGIS 2.16.3 (Windows 7), and a recent QGIS build v2.99 (GNU/Linux). This is not a bug due to the PyQGIS code above, in fact, creating the virtual layer from QGIS GUI (either from `DB Manager` or `Manage Layers Toolbar`) I get the same result. Can you confirm such behavior?*

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, I will test this later today and report back =)

Comment: Up until loading the virtual layer works fine. But when I change the URI using the first `setDataSource()`, the attribtute table is empty. When changing to the last two `setDataSource()`, I receive the following error: `Query preparation error on SELECT Count(*), Min(MbrMinX(""),Min(MbrMinY(""), Max(MbrMaxX(""), Max(MbrMaxY("") FROM : near " ": syntax error`

Comment: And you're using QGIS v...? Have you reproduce that error using NE dataset?

Comment: Nope, my fault. There was an extra letter in the path, it works now (tested on QGIS 2.18.0 for Win7 64-bit). Many thanks! I can also confirm the bug, it seems any feature you try to select, the very first feature in the layer gets selected. I also noticed when moving the canvas, other features are highlighted as if they are selected but is not shown in the attribute table. I will think about whether to implement this into my plugin in its current state... :)

Comment: Yeap, doesn't seem to be an option yet. Strangely, I hadn't notice that problem using Virtual Layers before from the QGIS GUI. I'll check later if there is already a reported issue about it or I'll create it.

Comment: In fact, a related issue existed. I updated it with more details: https://hub.qgis.org/issues/15134

Comment: Thanks Germán, looks like the author of the plugin is in the process of [committing a fix](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/3794). Nice!!!

Comment: Great! It's a very powerful QGIS feature, it would be a pity to discard it by that bug.